# How to set a correct background color in a composite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

i have a problem with a panel in Eclipse 3.7

I have a composite in the panel, and the background is "white", but the panel is gray ( or default ).

Which one is the attribute I have to set, to let the background of the composite use the background color of the panel ?

[image]

as you can see I hace the composite in a "container".

I also have the same problem with a Group composite.

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards

Edit: add a little of source code!

```
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    this.container = container;

    ...
    Composite informacion_xml = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    informacion_xml.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, false, 2, 1));
    formToolkit.adapt(informacion_xml);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(informacion_xml);
    informacion_xml.setLayout(new FormLayout());

    Label lblNewLabel = new Label(informacion_xml, SWT.NONE);
    FormData fd_lblNewLabel = new FormData();
    fd_lblNewLabel.top = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    fd_lblNewLabel.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(fd_lblNewLabel);
    formToolkit.adapt(lblNewLabel, true, true);
    lblNewLabel.setText("Fecha y hora Exportación");

    textFechaExportacion = new Text(informacion_xml, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    fd_lblNewLabel.right = new FormAttachment(textFechaExportacion, -15);
    FormData fd_textFechaExportacion = new FormData();
    fd_textFechaExportacion.bottom = new FormAttachment(0, 27);
    fd_textFechaExportacion.top = new FormAttachment(0, 8);
    fd_textFechaExportacion.left = new FormAttachment(0, 161);
    fd_textFechaExportacion.right = new FormAttachment(63);
    textFechaExportacion.setLayoutData(fd_textFechaExportacion);
    formToolkit.adapt(textFechaExportacion, true, true);

    Label lblDispositivo = new Label(informacion_xml, SWT.NONE);
    lblDispositivo.setText("Dispositivo");
    FormData fd_lblDispositivo = new FormData();
    fd_lblDispositivo.top = new FormAttachment(lblNewLabel, 10);
    fd_lblDispositivo.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    fd_lblDispositivo.bottom = new FormAttachment(67, -1);
    lblDispositivo.setLayoutData(fd_lblDispositivo);
    formToolkit.adapt(lblDispositivo, true, true);

    textDispositivo = new Text(informacion_xml, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    fd_lblDispositivo.right = new FormAttachment(textDispositivo, -15);
    FormData fd_textDispositivo = new FormData();
    fd_textDispositivo.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -25);
    fd_textDispositivo.top = new FormAttachment(textFechaExportacion, 6);
    fd_textDispositivo.left = new FormAttachment(0, 161);
    fd_textDispositivo.right = new FormAttachment(100, -200);
    textDispositivo.setLayoutData(fd_textDispositivo);
    formToolkit.adapt(textDispositivo, true, true);
    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
```

Comment: Show us the actual code being generated. Also note that Eclipse 3.7 is 11 releases and 8 years out of date.

Comment: hi @greg-449 , yes I know. Is a legacy app. A few year ago try to upgrade, but didn't went well...

Comment: You seem to be using `FormToolkit` - which forces a white background. Don't use this in a wizard page.

Comment: Amazing @greg-449 !! I'm using WindowBuilder editor. I have a lot to learn! Thanks Again!